# Detect browser support of the Scroll-To-Text Fragment (:~:text=) feature?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, scroll-to-text

Google recently started to roll out the *Scroll-To-Text Frament* feature in their highlighted snippets. Doing so it appends `#:~:text=...` parameter to linked url which is used by the browser to highlight the snippets text on the targets website.

As for now (July 2020), *Scroll-To-Text Fragment* is a [W3C Community Group Draft Report](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/) and the [browser support is very limited](https://caniuse.com/#feat=url-scroll-to-text-fragment) (basically Chromium based browsers as of today).

My question is: is there any way to detect whether a browser supports this feature? I.e. using javascript?

Comment: I do not well understand how this feature is used and coded. In CSS you can check if a feature is supported by the browser using the query `@supports (property = value) {}`. I am not sure is that can help you.

Comment: This is not a CSS based feature, so I don't think you can use CSS to determine whether it is supported. Browsers read this parameter from the URL, search for the given text and (in case they find it) scroll the page directly to the first position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the spec](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/#feature-detectability):

> ### [3.7. Feature Detectability](https://wicg.github.io/scroll-to-text-fragment/#feature-detectability)
>
> For feature detectability, we propose adding a new `FragmentDirective`
> interface that is exposed via `document.fragmentDirective` if the
> UA supports the feature.
>
> ```
> [Exposed=Window]
> interface FragmentDirective {};
> ```
>
> We amend the `Document` interface to include a `fragmentDirective`
> property:
>
> ```
> partial interface Document {
>     [SameObject] readonly attribute FragmentDirective fragmentDirective;
> };
> ```

So you can test this using

```
const isAvailable = "fragmentDirective" in window.document;
```

or

```
const isAvailable = !!window.FragmentDirective;
```

Comment: Looks like thy have changed it. It should be "fragmentDirective" in document; now

Comment: @stillwaiting Thanks, updated according to [the issue](https://github.com/WICG/scroll-to-text-fragment/issues/130)